# Как вывести описание всех портов коммутатора?

Tags: сеть, сетевое-программирование, коммутатор, d-link

Команда коммутатора `show ports description` выводит описание портов. Минус этой команды в терминале - вывод 1-4 портов (вывод в страницах), то есть для просмотра всех остальных обязательно нужно нажимать кнопки next или previous.

А есть ли способ чтобы получить всё сразу? Веб-интерфейс не интересует.